# Magento Open Source 2.3 / 2.2 - How many orders / inventary and SKU it can handle?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, api, magento2.3

I'm about to start a project, But my concerned is on the data, the magento 2.2/2.3 can handle.  The traffic figures are in 1 Million to 5 million  and we are not interested in Enterprise model as of now. My questions are very straigth foward and open for technical also. My questions ...

1. How many Orders / inventory can Magento Open Source modal can handle? Figures is aroung 8,00,000 monthly
2. If we have 10 billion sales each year, will magento be able handle 5 or 10 years data. I know that backend we have MYSQL but will it ?
3. How many products details i.e SKU it can handle again the data is in billions.

So let me know your figures for this.

Comment: Does this helpful to you?

Comment: @Aasim Thanks for the insights. How can I sacle the magento to handle 10,000 traffic a day. This volume is during campaigns which we run almost once a month. Also How about marketplace integration an you suggest some?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146182)

Answer (score 1):

- Magento 2 can handle as many products as you want **there is no catalog limit with magento2 CE or EE**.
- If you have more then 500k products then it might take some time to upload these products.
- It might even make your website slow depending on the hosting provider.
- It even depends on database you are using on back-end, MYSQL is relatively slow when querying large data.
- You might want some good database for example: Mysql-Percona,Oracle.

You can also check this url for more reference : https://aionhill.com/how-many-products-can-magento-handle